# Thinking Sphinx is called instead of activerecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, thinking-sphinx

I have a Job model which has_many Reports. The Report model has a scope...

scope :undeleted, where(:deleted => 0)

If I call the scope from the job like so...

@job.reports.undeleted

I get...

Sphinx Query (16.3ms)  @deleted 0
Sphinx  Found 0 results

But if I call it like...

@job.reports.where(:deleted => 0)

I get...

Report Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `reports`.* FROM `reports` WHERE `reports`.`job_id` = 1907 AND `reports`.`deleted` = 0

and it returns a single result which is what's expected.

Why is Thinking Sphinx being called at all in this case? And this only happens in production not in development. Thinking Sphinx is running in both environments.

Comment: Do you have any Thinking Sphinx scopes?

Comment: I have not declared any. Just indexes.

Comment: Oh s**t. There is one. My application is so big I can't remember half the stuff I put in there. I feel silly.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As discussed in the comments, the issue here is a Sphinx scope and an ActiveRecord scope sharing the name `undeleted`.

I'm not entirely sure why sometimes one takes priority, and sometimes the other, though I dare say it's due to the class reloading of Rails in a development environment.